# Subtract Values from two Rows

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

Need to calculate the difference in the attribute value of two features in ArcGIS.

e.g.

```
Field2(Row2)= Field1 (Row1)  - Field1(Row2)

Field2(Row3)= Field1(Row2)  - Field1(Row3)

Field2(Row4)= Field1(Row3)  - Field1(Row4)
```

....So on

```
Field2(Row1)= Field1(Row6) - Field1(Row1)
```

Any tips to achieve this using script/field calculator in ArcGIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cursors instead of Field Calculator. If you want absolute differences change:

```
differences = (j-i for i, j in zip(values[:-1], values[1:]))
```

To:

```
differences = (abs(j-i) for i, j in zip(values[:-1], values[1:]))
```

.

```
import arcpy

#Change to match your data:
fc = r'C:\database\feature_class'
field1 = 'Field1'
field2 = 'Field2'

#List all values in field1
values = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, field1)]

#Generator which return differences
differences = (j-i for i, j in zip(values[:-1], values[1:]))  

#Update field2
count=0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if count > 0: #Skip first row
            row[0] = differences.__next__()
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        count+=1
```

Screenshot from Pro but is is the same in Desktop:
[image]

Comment: Tx, works perfectly!